# Orphan a branch in TFS

Tags: tfs

Suppose I create an experimental branch in TFS.  Now, I am finished with the branch, and I want to keep it around, but it has diverged sufficiently from the source branch that I want to make sure that no one can merge it back on accident.  Is there a command in TFS to sever a branch, so that there is no merge path back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will prevent a merge but in TFS 2010 you can turn a branch in to a folder

Check out [Buck Hodges blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2010/09/30/how-to-convert-a-branch-back-to-a-regular-folder.aspx) on the subject

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can set permissions on a branch.

Comment: Yah,  I though tabout that too, but I can't think of a way to use permissions to prevent this.  I do not want to make my main branch read-only, or prevent it from accepting all merges, because it does accept merges from other branches (we use the feature branching pattern).  I can make my experimental branch read-only, but I don't think that will prevent anyone from merging it.  I could deny all rights to the experimental branch, but then deleting it would probably be more succinct.

Comment: You have an explicit 'Merge' permission attribute for each branch. This should do the job, if I understand it correctly (didn't try that yet on my own...).